# Conditional with might

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, conditional-constructions

The example:
"If she had time, she might go to the party"

This is the Present Real Conditional Form (as I found in a grammar website).

Does using "might" here mean:

1- "I am not certain (now) whether she went to the party or not".

OR

2- " I was uncertain (in the past) that she went.

If it means "in the past" why then it is called the Present Real Conditional Form ?

If the uncertainty exists in the present, them Why  the sentence doesn't just use "may" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence appears [here](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/presentconditional.html) as an example of the *Present Unreal Conditional* form. In [another place on that site](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html) this form is referred to as *Future Unreal Conditional*. In other places it is known as the [Second conditional](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional_3.htm) form.

You can identify this form by the first verb being in the past simple tense.

Looking at the source of the sentence (the first link above), the example is explained to use "might" as a replacement for "*would may", so it talks about a hypothetical *option* (as in "may or may not"). This option may apply either in the present or in the future, but either way it is unreal; the sentence suggests that *she doesn't have time*.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, what I get is that "Might" has a specific meaning if it come in the conditional sentences.